# master skin file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, themes, skin

My project has multiple themes with different colors.
I need to skin certain textboxes with a specific font/size/etc.[no color difference]
Currently, I add `<asp:TextBox SkinID="skinned" runat="server".../>` to all .skin files under each theme.
Is there a way to put this textbox skin in one place, like a master skin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to list it under each theme, but you only need to list one control definition per theme. If you want a skin to be the default behavior for a control, specify the definition without a SkinID property.

Comment: thanks...I modified my question to be for certain textboxes.  However, you still answered my question...it needs to be listed in each skin file...

Answer (score 5):

The lack of inheritance or cascading in the **ASP.NET Themes** implementation is an unfortunate limitation that doesn't receive a lot of attention. In scenarios where you wish to have a global skin available to *all* themes (without changing the control definition itself), you have two options:

**Option #1: Use a VirtualPathProvider**

(The downside of this is that you can't use it on precompiled websites without a reflection-based [workaround](http://labs.episerver.com/en/Blogs/Ted-Nyberg/Dates/112276/9/How-to-make-virtual-path-providers-work-with-precompiled-EPiServer-websites/).)

You can define a **Global.skin** file under a special **Global** theme where shared skins are kept; you will also create a placeholder Global.skin file under all other themes as well:

```
App_Themes
- Global
  \Global.skin (primary)
- ThemeA 
  \Global.skin (empty placeholder)
- ThemeB
  \Global.skin (empty placeholder)
```

In the **VirtualPathProvider** you would then re-route all requests for **App_Themes\*\Global.skin** to **App_Themes\Global\Global.skin**.

**Option #2: Use a Post-Build Task**

This is an amendment to the above solution that avoids the precompiled websites limitation; instead of doing the re-route at runtime, you can apply it post-build via an ms-build task that simply propagates **Global\Global.skin** to all other theme folders.

I've used both options successfully.